# Как организовать getters в redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Создаём хранилище store, затем actions и actions creator и затем выполняем dispatch для добавления нового цвета например на основе action.
Но как писать getters из хранилища? У каждого компонента свои методы get из store или все должны быть там же где и состояние приложения?

```
// Создаём хранилище 
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({colors, sort}),
  initialStateStore
)

// Добавляем новый цвет 
store.dispatch({
    type: C.ADD_COLOR,
    id: 5,
    title: 'Яркий желтый',
    color: 'yellow',
    rating: 0
})


// ?? тут получаем весь state
store.getState()

store.getColorsWhereRatingMore(7); // ? где реализовать этот метод
```

Метод getColorsWhereRatingMore может быть довольно большим по объему. Там должны быть запросы к БД?

Comment: Компонент получает данные через пропсы. Пропсы формируются методом connect библиотеки redux. То есть в моем понимании цепь такая: меняется состояние - меняются пропсы у компонента - компонент обновляется с новыми данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reducer:

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_DATA':
            return action.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Функция для получения данных из стора

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.data
    }
};
```

Функция для записи данных в стор:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setData: (params) => dispatch(params)
    }
};
```

Добавляем эти функции через коннект:

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(MyComponent)
```

Вот так будет выглядеть добавление данных в стор:

```
const data = {
   type: 'SET_DATA',
   data: {id: 1, value: "value"}
};
this.props.setData(data);
```

А то, что вытащим из стора будет доступно как `this.props.data`