# Dispatch и State

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть две функции, которые изображены на скрине

У двух функций есть по одному параметру: state и dispatch 

Внизу как я понимаю эти функции вызываются, но как в эти функции передается state и dispatch? Или это глобальные переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, внизу эти функции не вызываются, а добавляются в ваши пропсы. mapStateToProps функция нужна для получения данных из вашего глобального стэйта, а mapDispatchToProps нужна для записи данных. Вот есть пример - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876953/207550

Comment: Хорошо, то что они не вызываются, а добавляются - это я понял
Но как в них попадает параметр dispatch и state?

Comment: state - это глобальное состояние, с помощью connect() вы теперь можете к нему обратиться и достать что вам нужно. dispatch - что бы вы могли записывать. Вы должны будете вызвать функцию simpleAction и передать туда что вам необходмсо